# Substring selection within specific repetition of characters

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I've been looking around and I've almost arrived at an answer but I just can't put my finger on it.

I'd like to select values after an nth forward slash and before the next forward slash in a URL.

So, for example: In the following URL... https://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar/thisValue/more/text/ I'd like to return thisValue (after the fifth forward slash).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: A Java tag was added via edit and is now removed. How is this related to Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http:\/\/([^\/]+\/){n}([^\/]+).*$
```

n=3 in your example

Answer (score 2):

You could skip the regex and use [`split_part`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

> Split `string` on `delimiter` and return the given field (counting from one).

For example:

```
=> select split_part('http://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar/thisValue/more/text/', '/', 6);
 split_part 
------------
 thisValue
```

Don't forget the empty part caused by the doubled slashes in `http://`.

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted solution didn't work for me. This does:

```
SELECT substring('http://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar/thisValue/more/text/'
                ,'^http://(?:[^/]*/){3}([^/]+)')
```

Explain:

```
^       .. anchor left  
(?:     .. non-capturing parenthesis  
[^/]*   .. 0-n character being not "/"  
{3}     .. last element 3 times  
([^/]+) .. 1-n characters not "/", this time in capturing parenthesis
```

[More in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Comment: Did you try mu's? That worked for me and is much more readable than a regex.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: You are right, mu's solution is just fine. I was put off by the accepted answer, that's not working for me. Since the question is tagged [regex] I was looking for a regex solution.